# Powershell how to kill a particular program when the script window is closed?

Tags: python, bash, powershell

I want to start two python programs via a powershell script, and then close them when the powershell script exits by closing the terminal or window in which the script is running. So far my tried method has been unsuccessful.

Id also like to do something like this for Linux via a bash script.

The code i have tried is below:

```
# Define the paths to your Python scripts
$webuiScript = "WebUI\manage.py runserver"
$rpiApiScript = "PiCode\rpi-api-simulation.py"

# Open a URL in the default web browser
Start-Process "http://127.0.0.1:8000"

# Start the Django WebUI + Server without displaying a terminal window
Start-Process -FilePath "python.exe" -ArgumentList "$webuiScript" -WindowStyle Hidden
Write-Host "Django WebUI Started."

# Start the Flask RPi API without displaying a terminal window
Start-Process -FilePath "python.exe" -ArgumentList "$rpiApiScript" -WindowStyle Hidden
Write-Host "Flask RPi API Started."

# Monitor for the script's window close event
$scriptWindow = Get-Process -Id $PID
$scriptWindow.WaitForExit()

# Terminate all running Python processes
Get-Process -Name "python" | ForEach-Object { Stop-Process -Id $_.Id -Force }

Write-Host "Django WebUI & Flask API Stopped."
```

Comment: "*something like this for Linux via a bash script.*" -- This is the default on Linux. You don't have to do anything special for that to work, unless you did something special to start the python programs *detached* from their parent process (e.g. by wrapping them in `nohup` or `screen`).